# Rstudio, R Markdown - Knit HTML : the device doesn't recognize the command

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am working on Rstudio.

I am trying to convert a .Rmd file into a HTML file. When i click on "Knit HTML", the program opens up and alert box saying "The device does not recognize the command."

Alternatively, when i Try File->New File ->R Markdown I get the alert box saying "Creating R Markdown documents requires an updated version of the rmarkdown package. Do you want to install this package now ?"

When i click yes, a console appears but i can't copy/paste it because the console closes as soon as the (maybe failed) download finishes.

Comment: Install the package via `install.packages("rmarkdown")` and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing both `rmarkdown` + its dependencies from a plain R session:

```
deps <- tools::package_dependencies("rmarkdown")$rmarkdown
install.packages(deps)
install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

Then try again.